# different dates give same TIMEDIFF

Tags: sql

I am trying to calculate the time between two different dates. I calculate it to seconds with this sql command `FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, post.created)) / 60)`
but it returns the same value for different dates like the date `2021-11-05 14:49:13` and the date `2021-12-16 21:31:09` both return the value `50339`for the newer dates this method works just fine but for some reasen it does not work for those dates.

here is the data from the database in JSON format. left the difference from the Current timstamp to the date the item was created

```
{"Difference":"50339","created":"2021-11-05 14:49:13","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"50339","created":"2021-11-05 14:49:13","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"50339","created":"2021-12-09 18:12:47","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"50339","created":"2021-12-09 18:13:16","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"50339","created":"2021-12-09 18:13:44","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"50339","created":"2021-12-14 21:29:58","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"50339","created":"2021-12-14 21:41:33","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"50339","created":"2021-12-14 21:42:09","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"50339","created":"2021-12-15 18:58:22","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"50339","created":"2021-12-15 19:00:46","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"50339","created":"2021-12-16 18:26:55","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"50339","created":"2021-12-16 21:31:07","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"50339","created":"2021-12-16 21:31:08","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"50339","created":"2021-12-16 21:31:09","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"50339","created":"2021-12-16 21:31:09","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"49002","created":"2021-12-18 17:01:37","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"48831","created":"2021-12-18 19:53:09","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"43467","created":"2021-12-22 13:17:00","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"43467","created":"2021-12-22 13:17:01","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"43467","created":"2021-12-22 13:17:02","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"43467","created":"2021-12-22 13:17:02","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"43466","created":"2021-12-22 13:17:22","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"43464","created":"2021-12-22 13:19:57","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"43464","created":"2021-12-22 13:20:07","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"40784","created":"2021-12-24 09:59:46","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"38857","created":"2021-12-25 18:06:24","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"38827","created":"2021-12-25 18:37:17","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"38826","created":"2021-12-25 18:37:37","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"37542","created":"2021-12-26 16:02:13","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"37540","created":"2021-12-26 16:03:24","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"35918","created":"2021-12-27 19:05:51","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"35917","created":"2021-12-27 19:06:35","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"18531","created":"2022-01-08 20:52:38","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"18531","created":"2022-01-08 20:52:39","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"15640","created":"2022-01-10 21:04:07","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"15640","created":"2022-01-10 21:04:11","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"15640","created":"2022-01-10 21:04:12","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"15640","created":"2022-01-10 21:04:13","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"15640","created":"2022-01-10 21:04:14","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"15640","created":"2022-01-10 21:04:16","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"15640","created":"2022-01-10 21:04:17","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"15640","created":"2022-01-10 21:04:17","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"15640","created":"2022-01-10 21:04:18","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"13193","created":"2022-01-12 13:51:15","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"},
{"Difference":"29","created":"2022-01-21 17:14:50","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP":"2022-01-21 17:44:20"}
]
```

Comment: The provided formula calculates minutes not seconds. Please edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TIMEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) function in MySQL returns a [TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) value which has a range of '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'.

> TIME values may range from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'.

The time difference of `2021-11-05 14:49:13` and `2021-12-16 21:31:09` from `2022-01-21 17:44:20` will be `1850:55:07` and `860:13:11` respectively. Both of these are outside the defined range of TIME values so they will be trimmed to the nearest value i.e. `838:59:59`.

> By default, values that lie outside the TIME range but are otherwise valid are clipped to the closest endpoint of the range. For example, '-850:00:00' and '850:00:00' are converted to '-838:59:59' and '838:59:59'.

`838:59:59` => `3020399` seconds => `50339` minutes (approx.)

To overcome this issue, you can use the [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function or [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function (Convert the values to seconds first and then subtract).